# ÉUA ou USA ou ÉU

Tags: usage, abréviations, toponymes, géographie

Quelle abréviation faut-il utiliser pour États-Unis d'Amérique ? Dans un exposé (diapositive d'une présentation) j'avais écrit :

> Maîtrise en langue anglaise, Université du Michigan (ÉUA)

Une collègue, locutrice native du français, me dit d'enlever ÉUA et met USA. A-t-elle raison ? Pourquoi ?

Comment: Related: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/19065/what-is-the-most-common-name-for-the-us-in-french

Answer (score 13, accepted):

En français informel en France, on dit assez souvent « US », en prononçant les deux lettres séparément ([y.ɛs]). On dit aussi USA (aussi avec les lettres prononcées séparément). On n'utilise jamais l'abréviation française à l'oral. À l'écrit, on écrit souvent USA ou un peu moins souvent US dans des contextes informels.

Une petite minorité de Français pédants prétendent encore aujourd'hui comprendre « l'[Union Sud-Africaine](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_d%27Afrique_du_Sud) » quand on fait référence à un pays qui s'appelle « USA », même si ce n'est plus le nom officiel du pays depuis 1961 (et ça n'a jamais été un nom courant).

Dans un contexte formel, en principe, on écrit et on dit « États-Unis » (sans préciser d'Amérique sauf si on veut donner le nom formel complet¹). Le nom est suffisamment court pour qu'il ne soit pas utile de l'abréger. L'abréviation « ÉUA » existe (voire EUA chez les gens qui ne savent pas taper les accents), mais elle est très marginale. L'abréviation « USA » est de plus en plus utilisée dans des contextes formels (exemple : [un titre d'article du *Monde*](https://www.lemonde.fr/economie/article/2013/08/05/les-usa-accusent-bp-de-manipulation-des-prix-du-gaz_3457805_3234.html), mais on notera que c'est uniquement dans le titre de l'article, ou le nom de la société a également été abrégé, et le corps de l'article utilise « États-Unis »).

Dans le contexte d'un exposé ou d'un CV, le bon choix est donc « États-Unis », pas tant parce que l'abréviation USA serait un anglicisme que parce qu'il n'y a aucune raison d'utiliser une abréviation.

> Maîtrise en langue anglaise, **u**niversité **du** Michigan (**États-Unis**)

C'est l'université *du* Michigan, pas *de* Michigan, parce que *le* Michigan est une région, pas une ville. Les noms de régions prennent un article. (En règle générale, on met un article pour ce qui est un trait ou une surface sur une carte, comme les pays, régions, grandes îles, archipels, cours d'eau et chaînes de montagnes, et pas d'article pour ce qui est un point, comme les villes et les petites îles. Mais il y a des exceptions : les sommets de montagnes prennent un article, et les îles lointaines ne prennent pas d'article.) Et on ne met pas de majuscule au nom commun dans des expressions comme « université de … ».

¹  <sub>Je n'ai jamais rencontré de pédant francophone qui prétende que cela puisse désigner les États-Unis mexicains.</sub>

Comment: Je connais un Mexicain francophone à qui il arrive de dire par facétie qu'il vient des Etats-Unis.

Comment: je suis tout à fait d'accord avec vous concernant l'emploi d'Etats-Unis. Toutefois, je laisserais la majuscule d'**U**niversité du Michigan, car il s'agit ici d'un nom propre (et non d'une quelconque université sise dans le Michigan. )

Answer (score 5):

Voici un Ngram qui montre que l'abréviation **USA** est utilisée aujourd'hui avec une majorité écrasante par rapport aux autre formes abrégées.

[image]

La version sans A final (**US**) était plus fréquente après la libération mais a été rattrapée et dépassée autour de 1970 :

Les abréviations basées sur le nom français sont extrêmement peu utilisées, même si **EUA** commence à être détecté à la fin des années affichées.

Aucune abréviation contenant la majuscule accentuée É n'est trouvée par Google Ngram en dehors d'**É.-U.** qui a eu une période de popularité entre 1950 et 1960 et dont l'usage s’accroît de nouveau durant les années récentes.

Comme Gilles, je recommanderais d'utiliser **États-Unis** dans un CV, comme on mettrait **Royaume-Uni**, **Allemagne** ou **Grèce** et pas **U.K.**, **All.**/**D** ou **Gr.**/**EL**.

[image]

Comment: J'ai bien peur que la majorité des textes répertoriés par ngrams n'aient pas été digitalisés en considérant la posibilité de majuscules accentuées.

Comment: @Survenant9r7 Je ne fais que rapporter ce que trouve Google dans les publications qu'il a numérisées. Je suis bien conscient qu'il y a des différences significatives entres les usages du Québec/Canada francophone et le reste de la francophonie. Je pense que le succès d'USA tient pour beaucoup dans sa facilité de prononciation [y.ɛs.a] alors que [e.y] est difficilement identifiable.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Il y a sûrement des erreurs et des oublis mais je ne pense pas que ce soit significatif. La numérisation / reconnaissance de caractères prend en compte les accents. C'est la présence de voyelles accentuées dans les sigles qui est plutôt rare, mais ce n'est par le cas avec **É.-U.** qui est plus courant qu'**E.-U.**.

Comment: Aussi pourquoi inclure « aux » dans la recherche ? Il me semble que « aux » a plus de chances d'apparaitre dans un texte où l'abréviation n'est pas attendue.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez En mettant *US* et *USA* isolés, j'avais beaucoup trop de faux positifs, en y préfixant *aux* ou *les*, il n'y en a presque plus.

Comment: Ok, mais pour É.-U./E.-U. le graphe à une allure bien diférente (probablement peu fiable tout de même). Et c'est aussi bien dommage qu'on n'ait pas un corpus plus récent.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez [graphe](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%5B%C3%89.-U.%5D%2C%5BE.-U.%5D%2C%5B%C3%89.-U%5D%2C%5BE.-U%5D&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%5B%C3%89.-U.%5D%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%5BE.-U.%5D%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2C%5B%C3%89.-U.%5D%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%5BE.-U.%5D%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @jlliagre Je comprends. Mais États-Unis est au moins aussi facile à prononcer que _USA_ avec ses hiatus et pourquoi utiliser une abréviation correspondant à des mots anglais pour ensuite la prononcer à la française dans un texte si on a le nom en français. Par ailleurs je ne prononce pas à la française un terme que je reconnais comme étant un mot anglais de sorte que je prononce systématiquement /juː ɛs ˈeɪ/ ; dans mon environnement sociolinguistique, il est généralement mal perçu de prononcer à la française un terme de langue anglaise ; et plus facile de prononcer le français que l'anglais...

Comment: Il m'est impossible d'analyser correctement les articles des quotidiens québécois finalement même si j'ai l'impression que les titres d'articles emploient presque systématiquement États-Unis ou É.-U.. Les articles eux-mêmes contiennent des titres dans les textes ou des commentaires d'utilisateurs contenant _USA_, ou peuvent être rédigés par des contributeurs anglophones etc. _Trends_ est incapable de discriminer selon la langue et fait abstraction des faibles volumes etc. Je n'ai pas envie d'éplucher le corpus d'articles à bras. Mais j'ai modifié ma réponse pour tenir compte d'une nuance.

Comment: @Survenant9r7 Oui, on utilise de toute façon beaucoup plus souvent États-Unis qu'USA à l'écrit comme à l'oral. Quant à la prononciation, USA s'est francisé. Le prononcer /ju: ɛs ˈeɪ/ serait tout de suite remarqué ici, comme le serait /si ai e/ plutôt que /se i a/ (CIA). C'est l'inverse avec /ɛf be i/ qui ne serait pas compris immédiatement, tout le monde disant /ɛf bi ai/ (FBI). Côté Québec, Il y a un contre-exemple avec la prononciation de Boston qui nous surprend toujours. Los Angeles est aussi il me semble prononcé différemment.

Comment: Bons points. J'suis pas une référence, souvent j'ai un meilleur anglais que d'autres ici. _CIA_ je peux entendre les 2, pour une raison ou une autre parfois c'est qualifié par « américaine ». _Los Angeles_ aussi, disons que ce serait _L.A_ à l'anglaise, j'entendrais davantage les gens dire  \lɔ.s‿ɑ̃.ʒɛl\ mais je dirais davantage \lɔ.s‿an.dʒə.lɛs\, et Wiktionnaire a les deux. Pour _Boston_ je ne sais pas vraiment ; je pense que c'est \bɔs.tɔ̃\ comme sur Wiktionnaire ou \ˈbɒːstɪn\ Nouv.-A,.  Je peux pas dire « aux /ju: ɛs ˈeɪ/ » ça fait Ô-U-S-A, ce serait _aux States/États_ mais c'est relâché...

Comment: Los Angeles possède au moins quatre prononciations distinctes courantes au Québec. Si la prononciation est plus homogène en France, il sera naturel que l’on tombât un jour sur une prononciation *surprenante* de la part de Québécois.

Comment: @Montéedelait Il y a des variantes ici aussi, présence (courante) ou non d'un [d] avant le [ʒ] et  prononciation ouverte ou fermée du premier *e* : \ʒə\ ou \ʒɛ\ mais la fin est toujours \lɛs\.

Comment: @jlliagre Quelques exemples à la québécoise: [lɔsɑ̃nd͜ʒəlɛːs], [lɔsɑ̃nʒəlɛːs], [lɔsãʒɛl], [lɔsɑ̃ʒlɛs]

Comment: Je me suis trompé c'était \ʒe\ ou \ʒɛ\ en France mais pas \ʒə\. C'est la troisième prononciation québécoise qui nous surprend.

Comment: Peut-être que c'est à cause du nom _Angèle_, comme dans [_Soeur Angèle_](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C5%93ur_Ang%C3%A8le), ou parce qu'_angelus_ était récité _ad nauseam_ à une certaine époque, quoique là ça se prononce comme é ou e et non è ? Je sais pas trop.

Answer (score 3):

J'aurais écrit **USA** tout simplement. Le nom étant d'origine anglaise je ne vois pas de problème à l'appeler comme tel.

De plus qu'EUA est peu commun et trop proche (à mon goût) d'EAU (Émirats arabes unis), pouvant donc facilement prêter à confusion.

Comment: J'avoue que j'ai moi aussi pensé à *Émirats arabes unis*, à *USA*, et même à *Union Européenne*… malgré l'accent et l'ordre des lettres inversés. Si ça avait été écrit *É.-U.*, là par contre j'aurais reconnu car il me semble qu'on le rencontre de plus en plus sous cette forme.

Answer (score 3):

Si j'avais à utiliser l'abréviation j'écrirais **É.-U.** parce que la forme courte est d'usage courant ([États-Unis](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89tats-Unis#%C3%89tymologie)) et parce ce que c'est cette abréviation qui est employée chez moi pour le nom du pays ([BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=2755)<sup>1</sup>, [Termium](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&srchtxt=%C3%A9tats-unis&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs), [*Clefs du français pratique*](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/clefsfp/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_e&page=9-xIoiYEowGs.html#zz9-xIoiYEowGs), ex. au [*Guide du rédacteur*](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/redac-srch?lang=fra&srchtxt=%E9tats-unis&i=1&cur=1&nmbr=&comencsrch.x=0&comencsrch.y=0), [page « USA » (homonymie) sur Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/USA_(homonymie))). En contexte j'écrirais tout simplement **États-Unis** car je ne vois pas vraiment le besoin d'utiliser l'abréviation, comme on l'a dit ailleurs.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> C'est le document de la BDL classé sous *Noms géographiques et gentilés > Noms de pays et gentilés > [Abréviations des noms de pays commençant par D-E-F-G](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=2755)*. La BDL comporte aussi une entrée classée sous *Les sigles, abréviations et symboles > Les abréviations > Listes d'abréviations > [Abréviations des mots qui commencent par E](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=2&t1=&id=1797)* contenant « une liste de mots dont les abréviations sont d'un usage courant » et cette liste réfère à « É.-U. ou USA » pour le mot « États-Unis ».</sub>

Comment: ex. [site:ledevoir.com "É.-U."](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&biw=1920&bih=939&ei=SxGkXODCNISb5gLnlLTABg&q=site%3Aledevoir.com+%22%C3%89.-U.%22&oq=site%3Aledevoir.com+%22%C3%89.-U.%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...92130.102373..103561...3.0..0.69.606.10......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.koP6wl6GXLs) ; [site:ledevoir.com "USA"](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&biw=1920&bih=939&ei=vRGkXKOYJKXz5gLP4IbACQ&q=site%3Aledevoir.com+%22USA%22&oq=site%3Aledevoir.com+%22USA%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...57198.58246..58533...0.0..0.77.258.4......0....1..gws-wiz.stjTCG201OE).

Comment: [site:ledevoir.com "États-Unis"](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&biw=1920&bih=939&ei=-BGkXMTZLKWp5wL7-YTgDA&q=site%3Aledevoir.com+%22%C3%89tats-Unis%22&oq=site%3Aledevoir.com+%22%C3%89tats-Unis%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...85293.93260..94667...3.0..0.140.1019.14j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.cMACDzHDZao).

Answer (score -6):

Il est préférable d'écrire « ÉUA », mais « EUA » est aussi [utilisé](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/EUA).

Comment: Ma collègue m'a dit que c'est mieux d'utiliser USA. A-t-elle raison ?

Comment: @Dimitris Si elle veut une soupe franco-anglaise, évidemment, c'est mieux !

Comment: Je n'ai jamais vu EUA, j'ai toujours vu et entendu USA, en France du moins. Je ne vois pas trop l'intérêt de vouloir absolument utiliser ÉUA, si l'usage de USA prévaut. Une langue est faite pour évoluer, ce n'est pas grave si elle inclut certains mots/sigles d'autres langues.
Après ça dépend du contexte, sur un document officiel, il est sans donc préférable d'utiliser ÉUA en effet, mais dans la vie courante, je ne vois pas trop l’intérêt

Comment: Cette réponse ne contient aucune information.

Comment: En français on dit « États Unis d'Amérique » . Le sigle pour cela est donné dans le lien que je fournis, à l'encyclopédie Wikipédia. De plus « USA » c'est de l'anglais et il n'y a aucune raison de le mélanger au français ; finalement j'ai toujours écrit « ÉUA » sauf erreur, c'est très bien comme cela, et je vais continuer (ça vous le fera rencontrer un peu plus).